# Time picker Plugin Not responding

Tags: jquery

I had installed Time picker plug in from **GitHub**. And tried a simple program to see how it works. But its not displaying anything:

I have copied the mentioned files **jquery.timepicker.min.css**  and  **jquery.timepicker.min.js** in my working folder as well.

Can someone please help me to understand what I am doing wrong.

```
<Head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="c:/xampp/htdocs/Test/jquery.timepicker.min.css">
 <script src="c:/xampp/htdocs/Test/jquery.timepicker.min.js"></script>
 </Head>
 <body>
       <input class ="timepicker">
 </body>

 <script >
       $(document).ready(function(){
             $('input.timepicker').timepicker({  });
        });
 </script>
```

Comment: 1. You need to include jQuery.js in the page as the timepicker relies on it 2. You may have security issues running JS code on your C: drive. Try installing a webserver locally and run on that

Comment: @Rory McCrossan, Thanks, I have added  jQuery.js as well. But still nothing coming up .

Comment: Make sure you include jQuery first. Also try checking the console for errors.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add JQuery file in your code. Check full code in JSfiddle : 

`Click Here`

Comment: Thanks I can see that its working ..but still unable to understand what I am doing wrong. As I have added Jquery file in the code but still not getting there.

Comment: Check your console and make sure your timepicker files are correct and they are accessible in your file ?